# Encountering 'Network Error' during Axios Request in Signup Page Implementation

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, cors

While creating a signup page for my medical pager chat application , i came through an error.

Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68835:14)
at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69287:41)
at async handleSubmit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:747:9)

how to fix this error !!!

I've tried using postman to check if the server responds and all are working properly, and ive also tried reconfiguring the dependencies , but can't figure it out !!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask